# How to iterate two List objects with enhanced for loops

Tags: java, loops, javafx

I'm trying to iterate though two lists using for loops, but I get as many times iterations as the number of items in each lists.

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList();
    l.add("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg");
    l.add("E:/IMG_1241.mp4");

    Image[] images = new Image[l.size()];
    ImageView[] pics = new ImageView[l.size()];

    for (final String imageResource : l) {

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
```

With the above the program produces final 4 items. If `List<String> l` had four items, then 16, ie 4 items iterated 4 times, if three 9 items.

I was thinkin a for loop like so `for (int i = 0, int iL; int iL < l.size(), i < l.size(); iL++, i++) {`, but I'm not sure how work it out.

Please help.

The full program looks something like so:

```
public class TilePaneExample {

    public javafx.scene.layout.TilePane listItems() {

        List<String> l = new ArrayList();
        l.add("C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3");
        l.add("C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv");
        l.add("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg");
        l.add("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");

        // Pane
        javafx.scene.layout.TilePane tilePane = new javafx.scene.layout.TilePane();
        tilePane.setHgap(2);
        tilePane.setVgap(2);
        tilePane.setMinWidth(250);

        Image[] images = new Image[l.size()];
        ImageView[] pics = new ImageView[l.size()];

        for (final String imageResource : l) {

            for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {

                final String imageResourceItem = l.get(i);
                images[i] = new Image("file:" + "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg");

                pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
                pics[i].setFitWidth(22);
                pics[i].setPreserveRatio(true);
                pics[i].setSmooth(true);

                pics[i].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        File f = new File(imageResourceItem);

                        String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                        if (imageResource.startsWith("file:")) {
                            absolutePath = absolutePath.replace("\\standAloneDev\\java\\workingDir\\live\\WakiliProject\\file:D:", "");
                        }

                        String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(absolutePath);

                        System.out.println("You clicked: " + absolutePath + ". The extension is: " + ext);
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(absolutePath));

                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(TilePaneExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                    }
                });
                tilePane.getChildren().add(pics[i]);

            }
        }

        return tilePane;
    }
}
```

I'm working with Windows 7 default sample files so should work without much modificatios. Try executing it and you'll get a picture of what I'm trying to get done.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

The application should work like this: there is an image for each link in `List l`, `l.add("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");` for example. There are as many images as there are links, hence two loops. The outer loop, `for (final String imageResource : l) {` gets the link, the inner one `for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {` creates the clickable image which when clicked opens the resource, video, picture or music file.

Comment: I only see one list...and two arrays. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why are you iterating the `List` twice?

Comment: I added an update explaining why I need two iterations @Elliott Frisch

Comment: I still don't understand why you need two loops. You only have **one** list.

Comment: "There are as many images as there are links" To me, this implies you only need **one** loop. Since you need the index of the loop, you should remove the outer "enhanced" for loop.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. If I only had image files that would work. But here I have a cluster of all possible file types. There is an image, could be a button, for each link. So two for loops, unless you could suggest another way how to

Comment: @user3663765 So do you really have two lists? One list for the button images and one for the resource link? This isn't what your source code here says...Even if you do have two lists like this, you still only need **one** loop because the lists are what we call "parallel lists".

Comment: Your title says "How to iterate two List objects..." but I only see one `List` in your code. Where is the second list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do it this way:

```
public class TilePaneExample {

public javafx.scene.layout.TilePane listItems() {

    List<String> l = new ArrayList();
    l.add("C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music/Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3");
    l.add("C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv");
    l.add("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Koala.jpg");
    l.add("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");

    // Pane
    javafx.scene.layout.TilePane tilePane = new javafx.scene.layout.TilePane();
    tilePane.setHgap(2);
    tilePane.setVgap(2);
    tilePane.setMinWidth(250);

    Image[] images = new Image[l.size()];
    ImageView[] pics = new ImageView[l.size()];

    //for (final String imageResource : l) { // removed first loop

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {

            final String imageResourceItem = l.get(i);
            images[i] = new Image("file:" + "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg");

            pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
            pics[i].setFitWidth(22);
            pics[i].setPreserveRatio(true);
            pics[i].setSmooth(true);

            pics[i].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    File f = new File(imageResourceItem);

                    String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    if (l.get(i).startsWith("file:")) { // changed the imageResourceItem into l.get(i)
                        absolutePath = absolutePath.replace("\\standAloneDev\\java\\workingDir\\live\\WakiliProject\\file:D:", "");
                    }

                    String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(absolutePath);

                    System.out.println("You clicked: " + absolutePath + ". The extension is: " + ext);
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(absolutePath));

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TilePaneExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
            });
            tilePane.getChildren().add(pics[i]);

        }
    }

    return tilePane;
//}
```

}

without the first loop you could still access your links using the: l.get(i)
what the first loop was doing was just assigning the contents of your List to final String imageResource which is then going to be used in your code: 
`if (imageResource.startsWith("file:")) {
                            absolutePath = absolutePath.replace("\\standAloneDev\\java\\workingDir\\live\\WakiliProject\\file:D:", "");
                        }` 
So what you could do to make it efficient is to remove that first loop and instead of using the imageResource for your conditional operator, you could use l.get(i) instead. No need for you to assign it to a String variable via the first loop.
Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to load the pictures whose file names are in the list `l`. This means you only need one `for` loop.

Comment: I added an update explaining why I need two iterations @Code-Apprentice

Comment: If I only had image files that would work. But here I have a cluster of all possible file types. There is an image, could be a button, for each link. So two for loops, unless you could suggest another way how to

Comment: @user3663765 If I understand correctly you want to create one button for each resource (which may have different file types). This seems to require a single for loop that iterates through your list of resources.